# Ставят ли в кавычки и оригинал переводимого слова, и перевод?

Tags: кавычки, переводы

Предложение звучит следующим образом:

> Группы эти олицетворяются пять групп "махабхут" или "материальных
> элементов".

В данном случае нужно ли ставить перевод санскритского слова в кавычки? А сам санскритский термин?